# Unit testing remote API? (in a Symfony2 bundle)

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I've created a very small symfony2 bundle here: https://github.com/BranchBit/AirGramBundle

Just a simple service, which calls a remote url.

Now, unit-testing-wise, should I even be testing this? Really all that can go wrong, is the remote host not being available, but that's not my code's issue.

If this were your bundle to maintain, what would you suggest, I would like 100% code coverage, however 50% of the code, is just calling the remote url ..

Suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to use a `HTTP client` instead of the direct call with the `file_get_content` so you can inject this via container. Them, in your unit test you can inject a mocked value of the http client that can define your desired behaviour (like wrong response or 500 etc). Hope this help. Let me know if you need some example.

Answer (score 0):

This test is unnecessary in my opinion. If you try to test it, then you can use `WebTestCase`. Your service in the Bundle should accept a `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client` for client implementation. You can choose between `Goutte\Client` for production firing with cURL or `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client` for testing. Then you have to dynamically add a route or a request listener.

Doesn't matter how, but the test is more complex than the implementation, so how can you be sure, your test is okay?

Comment: The only thing which makes sense is to pass a mock to your service an check if a call to your service invokes the `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client` in a right way. Then you should get a better code coverage.